# writing custom query in doophp

Tags: php, mysql, doophp

I am new to Doophp framework. I would like to write the following SQL query to be executed in Doophp. but I can't find any proper tutorials or reference regarding to this. Query is as follow;

> SELECT * FROM `m_company`  WHERE `comp_id` LIKE `%$search%` OR
>   `comp_kana` LIKE `%$search%` OR `comp_person` LIKE `%$search%`

Comment: '%$search%' add quotes around search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Doo db SmartModel you can use the "custom" paramters as here:
let's assume you have a model "company" so in controller

```
$this->loadModel("company");
$c = new company;

$company = $c->find(array("select" => "what you want", "where" => "your statement"));
```

bye